# handling exception in Spotfire python script

Tags: python-2.7, ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to replace multiple files in Spotfire using a python script, the script works perfectly well when it finds all the files in the destination folder, however, if even a single file is not present in the destination folder then it gives an alert that:

> file XYZ.xlsx is not found in the destination folder

Below is the code which works if all the files are found in the destination folder:

```
    from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataOperations import *
    from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
    from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataFlowBuilder

    # Search for the tables which need to be replaced and assign it to Tblnm                                        
    for table in Document.Data.Tables:
     if(table.Name[1:6]=="Input"):
       Tblnm=table.Name[8:20]
       sourceView=table.GenerateSourceView()

    #get the dat table data source operation
       op=sourceView.GetAllOperations[DataSourceOperation]()[0];

       DS=Document.Data.CreateFileDataSource("Folder");
       dataFlow = DataFlowBuilder(DS,Application.ImportContext).Build();

    #replace the data source
       if op.CanReplaceDataFlow():
         op.ReplaceDataFlow(dataFlow)
```

I have tried the below code it works in the python window but crashes the .dxp later on.

```
     try:
        if op.CanReplaceDataFlow():
           op.ReplaceDataFlow(dataFlow)
     except:
        print(Tblnm)
```